# data set in ngOnInit() is undefined in ngAfterViewInit()

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to get the data from Firebase and set it to a variable in the Class. The problem that I am facing is that the variable is undefined in the ngAfterViewInit().

I know for a fact that it is set in ngOnInit(). I have read up Angular lifecycle methods and the tour of heroes example in the Angular doc page to see if I am fetching the data correctly, but it still does not explain this strange behavior (at least to me!).

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/data.json').map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
    data => {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var a: string = data[i]['date'];
        data[i]['date'] = new Date(a);
      }
      this.timeline = data; // declared in class
      this.timelineElements = data; // declared in class
      console.log(data); // data is not empty
      console.log(TIMELINE); // data is not empty
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  )}


ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.timeline); // Undefined if fetched from firebase. Works perfectly if the data is fetched locally
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine if I try and set the the two variables locally. The problem is when I try and fetch it from firebase. 
I am new to Angular world, but my understanding is that maybe in my case, `ngAfterViewInit()` is invoked way before the data from Firebase arrives? Not sure though.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

http.get is an asynchronous function which means it takes time to complete. In this case ngAfterViewInit is called before http.get is completed.

Why do you want to seperate everything with ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit anyways?

Comment: I understand that. But is there a way to make by make angular wait until the data arrives(Literally to not let it proceed to ngAfterViewInit()). I tried SetTimeOut  function in ngOnInt(). But it does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath, only on the entire applicaiton level

Comment: Don't 'pause' the application. That's just bad user experience. What you can do is show a loading spinner or just hide the template content using the *ngIf directive.

Comment: @VarunBabuPozhath you cannot make it wait bad user experience, better use an observable if you dnt want to write async code

Comment: Basically I have a bunch of code that gets executer in ngAfterViewInit(). For this to work, the variables in ngOnInit() should be set. Any other work around ?

Comment: well, if those variables come from `http.get` then that's just bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care so much that your logic should be done in `ngAfterViewInit`?
Http call is async and whatever should happen on it receiving data should be done there and not in `ngAfterViewInit`.

View is initialized > `ngAfterViewInit` fired > you could load data way after that and you should be handling data in your subscription `onSuccess` function.

So:

```
.subscribe(
    data => {
    //this is where you should do whatever you need with the data
    //you should not care about ngAfterViewInit at all with respect to getting data
})
```

If you made some assumptions that you'll have data in any of your life-cycle hooks then you just made some bad assumptions and you'll need to redesign your component logic.
For help with that you should probably ask new question with component code.

Comment: I am fairly new to Javascript, TypeScript and Angular. I was just wondering if what I am trying to achieve is possible or not. Thanks for your answer. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: its possible but its really not something you should try doing. the whole framework is build around async paradigm and trying to force it to become sync is actually not learning angular but breaking it. you will be much better off if you ask new question with description what do you want to achieve and your components logic how you tried it. then we can give you the design proposals how to build it properly with async http calls ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you try to hit the api inside ngOnInit which is fine but you don't know how much time server will take for returning the response and at the same time Angular 2 having its own life cycle which is independent of your backend. Now come to the point Http. Followings are all types and stuff required to make and handle an HTTP request to a web service with Angular:

- **Http** is an Angular 2 service that provides the API to make HTTP
  requests with methods corresponding to HTTP verbs like get, post,
  put, etc
- **Response** is a type that represents a response from an HTTP service
  and follows the fetch API specification
- **Observable** is the async pattern used in Angular 2. The concept of
  observable comes from the observer design pattern as an object that
  notifies an interested party of observers when something interesting
  happens. In RxJS it has been generalized to manage sequences of data
  or events (also know as streams), to become composable with other
  observables and to provide a lot of utility functions known as
  operators that let you achieve amazing stuff.
- **rxjs/add/operator/map** refers to rxjs map operator. rxjs is a very big
  library with lots of operators and features. A best practice is to
  only import the parts of rxjs that you need to use and that’s why we
  start by only importing the map operator (one of the most commonly
  used operators).

So one of the solution is that beside getting the data in **ngAfterViewInit** you can call your own function inside the response:

like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/data.json').map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
    data => {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var a: string = data[i]['date'];
        data[i]['date'] = new Date(a);
      }
      this.timeline = data; // declared in class
      this.timelineElements = data; // declared in class
      console.log(data); // data is not empty
      console.log(TIMELINE); // data is not empty
      getTheData(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  )};

 this.getTheData(data){
     this.finalData = data;
 }
```

Comment: Hey I tried that. Even if you call getTheData(data) inside the subscribe call, it is not executed before ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: It is so because when you get the data from api it may take some time but the angular cycle will execute at any cost. Here what I mean to say just assign the response data in the variable for rendering at the view part.Don't forget to use {{finalData?.subData}} for rendering at template.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Had the same problem my value was not available in the NgAfterViewInit.

So I take my code from the OnInit and I place it in the Constructor()

```
constructor()
  { 
      code here 
  }
```

So After this, my value was available in the NgAfterViewInit.