# getting different data from an observable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am stuck in a issue while learning angular. While I get data from an Observable,inside a NgOnInit method, It is ok, the method bring the right value.The sad part is when i try to acess anywhere outside, it gives me a undefined array.**

```
    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'operacao',
      templateUrl: './operacao.component.html',
      providers: [Operacao],
      styleUrls: ['./operacao.component.css']
    })
    export class OperacaoComponent implements OnInit {

      private _operacao: Operacao;
      private _operacoes: any[];


    public rows: Array<any> = [];
    private myserviceService: MyserviceService;
...


 constructor(myservice: MyserviceService) {
    this.length = 10;
    this.myserviceService = myservice;

  }
    ...

ngOnInit() {
 this.myserviceService.getOperacoes()
  .subscribe((operacao) => {
    this._operacoes = operacao; 
    //here i get the "right" value
     console.log(this._operacoes); 
    //Array(2) [Object, Object]
    //0:Object {id: 0, acao_id: 0, user_id: "1", …}
    //1:Object {id: 1, acao_id: 1, user_id: "1", …}
```

myservice.ts

```
getOperacoes() {
      return this.http.get(this.url + 'operacoes').map(res => res.json());
   }
```

when i call, anywhere outside Subscribe()

```
console.log(this._operacoes);
```

i get undefined

Comment: http is an synchronous function. So it takes some time to complete [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031140/data-set-in-ngoninit-is-undefined-in-ngafterviewinit)

Comment: Typo -- ** Asynchronous